# localStorage get value using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I looked at some examples, but can't seem to figure this out.  Basically I have a contact form in an ionic app that allows a user to contact a listing owner.

When they submit the form I want to store the ad id in local storage so they can't repeatability submit it over and over.

I need to be able to store json array and then check the results. If the ad id is in session storage don't show the form else show it.

I am currently doing this, which seems to store the ad ids in an array, but how do I loop through to check if an id exists?  I tried angular forEach, but results come as an object.

```
    // Parse any JSON previously stored in allEntries
  var existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("store_owner_ad_contacts"));
  if(existingEntries == null) existingEntries = [];

  var adId = {
    "id":$scope.adId
  };
  // Save allEntries back to local storage
  existingEntries.push(adId);
  localStorage.setItem("store_owner_ad_contacts", JSON.stringify(existingEntries));

  var values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("store_owner_ad_contacts"));
  angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {

  // ^ This is coming as an object how can I get the key value?

   if(value == adId){
   //form has been submitted before
   }else{
   // showformVar = true 

    console.log(key + ': ' + value);
  });
```

My storage looks like this

```
      [{"id":"100033"},{"id":"100035"},{"id":"1000336"}]
```

How do I get id value?  (e.g 1000033)

Comment: what are you getting when you do `var values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("store_owner_ad_contacts"));` can you post it here?

Comment: Updated my question. I am getting -   [{"id":"100033"},{"id":"100035"},{"id":"1000336"}]  How do I get the id value? (e.g 1000033)

Comment: if you don't like `angular.forEach` then you can use simple javascript's for loop as described in @Sasank's answer

Comment: If I console.log(values) I get an object returned. Looking in localStorage its storing as  [{"id":"100033"},{"id":"100035"},{"id":"1000336"}].  I tried for loop same result.  I must be missing something.

Comment: you can use forEach https://jsfiddle.net/nxfmxqge/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your loop you have an object, so just access id property like you do with an object: object.yourProperty or object[yourProperty]

```
var values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("store_owner_ad_contacts"));

values.forEach(values, function(item, i) {

   // you get object like this {id: "100033"}
   // so to access id do like normal object

   if (item.id === '100033') {
     // do something
   }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// inside forEach loop
var k = 0;
for(k in value) {
     // u can get the key in this way (k) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  My storage looks like this  [{"id":"100033"},{"id":"100035"},{"id":"1000336"}]
How do I get id value? (e.g 1000033) This is where I am stuck.

Comment: @limit `JSON.parse(localStorage.get(yourKey))[0].id`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @FrankerZ I will try to write some explanations before writing the code . Thanks I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

As I see this is not about not about angular itself (using this in an angular doesn't mean relation). If you have an array of values and want to search for something then you can use `Array.prototype.find`.
if your data is stringified array then you should parse it before with `JSON.parse`.

If you're about to use localStorage in your angular app then that would be better to use [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) which handles stringify and parse and some more options.

```js
var lsItems = [{"id":"100033"},{"id":"100035"},{"id":"1000336"}];

var item = lsItems.find(i => i.id === "100035");
console.log(item)
```